# Laravel advanced search between product and relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I am kind of new to laravel, and would like to work with relationship behavior laravel provides.

I have a search function that searches;

Keywords,
Category,
Media Type,
Artist,
Minimum and Maximum Price

My tables are as follows (showing only pertinent data)

Table: products (model: Products)

```
id -> integer (primary)
name -> string
artist -> integer
active -> boolean
```

Table: options_products (model: ProductOptions)

```
id -> integer (primary)
products_id -> integer
price -> decimal(14,2)
active -> boolean
```

Table: categories (model: Category)

```
id -> integer (primary)
parent_id -> integer
name -> string
```

Table: category_products (model ProductCategories) <- Pivot table

```
products_id -> integer
category_id -> integer
```

Table: media_type (model: Media)

```
id -> integer (primary)
name -> string
```

Product Model

```
public function categories() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
}

public function options() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProductOptions');
}
```

ProductOptions Model:

```
public function mediaType()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Media', 'id', 'media');
}

public function product()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Products', 'id', 'products_id');
}

public function productsMany() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Products', 'id', 'products_id');
}
```

ProductCategories Model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Products', 'id', 'products_id');
}
```

Category Model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Products', 'category_products');
}

public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(self::class, 'parent_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

For the life of me i cannot figure out how to incorporate everything into the search, for example if they select a category, and min and max price, since the category is linked to the product table and the price is in the options_product table. Basically I need it to search either one argument, a few, or all arguments. I think I am out of my league as I searched and searched and could not find an answer unless i result in a raw query.

I have a rather long winded routine currently that handles most of the search options, separately however and not with the min and max pricing. For example for the text search:

Text Search:

```
if ($request->exists('search')) {
        /* filter & split */
        $search = Helpers::filter_search($request->get('search'));
        $products = Products::where(function ($q) use ($search) {
            foreach ($search as $value) {
                $q->orWhere('name', 'like', "%{$value}%");
                $q->orWhere('description', 'like', "%{$value}%");
            }
        })->where('active', 1)->paginate($views_per_page)->setPath('');
        $products->appends(array(
            'search' => $request->get('search')
        ));
    }
```

Here is the routine to get min/max:

```
if ($request->exists('min') || $request->exists('max')) {
        $min = ($request->get('min')) ?? 0.00;
        $max = ($request->get('max')) ?? null;
        $products = Products::with('options')
            ->whereHas('options', function($q) use ($min,$max) {
                $q->where('options_products.price', '>=', $min);
                if ($max) {
                    $q->where('options_products.price', '<=', $max);
                }
            })->where('active', 1)->paginate($views_per_page);

    }
```

Helper function:

```
public static function filter_search($query)
{
    $q = preg_split('/[;,+ ]+/', $query, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $q = preg_replace("/[^ \w-]/", "", $q);
    return $q;
}
```

So basically, I want to be able to put this all in one query if need be. So if they customer chooses the Artist, Category, Media, Min And/or Max Price, and text-search it will create one full query. Any help on this would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: It's kind of hard to help as you don't have an exact question but what helped me get my head around eloquent and query builder is to look at the queries that it built. Wrap your query in `\DB::enableQueryLog()` and `dd(\DB::getQueryLog())` and take a look at what it gives you.

Comment: I basically want to combine everything into one query

Comment: I can only spot one query. What queries are executing?

Answer (score 1):

Search Product name or products that have a category name

```
 $products = Product::with('category')->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $data['name'] . '%')->orWhere( function($query) use ($data){
                $query->whereHas('category', function($q) use ($data){
                    $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $data['name'] . '%');
                });
            })->get();
```

This can be modified to fit your need.